# Serialize object to element with attributes and children

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I wish to define classes that will produce the following xml using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.  I am struggling to get the items list, with attributes that does not contain a child 'container' element for 'item' elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<myroot>
   <items attr1="hello" attr2="world">
      <item id="1" />
      <item id="2" />
      <item id="3" />
   </items>
</myroot>
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, can't you create Items class which has a collection of Item class?

Comment: That's correct, but the items element has to have attributes.

Comment: Yes, can't we define other properties also inside items class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

with `XmlSerializer` things are ***either*** lists *or* they have members. To do that you need:

```
[XmlRoot("myroot")]
public class MyRoot {
    [XmlElement("items")]
    public MyListWrapper Items {get;set;}
}

public class MyListWrapper {
    [XmlAttribute("attr1")]
    public string Attribute1 {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("attr2")]
    public string Attribute2 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<MyItem> Items {get;set;}
}
public class MyItem {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

with example:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot));
var obj = new MyRoot
{
    Items = new MyListWrapper
    {
        Attribute1 = "hello",
        Attribute2 = "world",
        Items = new List<MyItem>
        {
            new MyItem { Id = 1},
            new MyItem { Id = 2},
            new MyItem { Id = 3}
        }
    }
};
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
```

which generates:

```
<myroot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <items attr1="hello" attr2="world">
    <item id="1" />
    <item id="2" />
    <item id="3" />
  </items>
</myroot>
```

you can remove the `xsi`/`xsd` namespace aliases if you want, of course.

Comment: Wow, awesome work Marc.  It was marking the 'Items' collection in the wrapper as simply XmlElement, rather than XmlArrayItem which I was missing.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but child members for me aren't being populated when there's only one within the xml. Any ideas why? Thanks :)

Comment: @Gareth almost certainly "yes, I can help with that", but it would really really help if you could show me the XML and the class(es) you're trying to use with it.